# Browser parsing formatted text code

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, mfc

I would like to build a program that accepts an input string then draws it as styled text in a MFC view. I am wondering how a string like the following will be displayed as styled text string when viewed in a browser.

```
"this is a string that < b >will< /b > < i >be displayed< /i > by your browser"
```

I would like to know how it reads `< b > < /b >` etc when it meets the string. What if the above string I would rewrite as:

```
"this is a string that < b >will < i >be < /b > displayed< /i > by your browser"
```

The word "be" now becomes both bold and italic.

I have no idea how to partition the long given string to smaller parts correctly. Do traditional web browsers implement this with a tree structure to process them? Would you mind offering a method or an example I can follow ?

Comment: How is this either C++ or MFC? What's the question?

Comment: Yes, it's a tree structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model

Comment: But: `< b >will < i >be < /b > displayed< /i >` is not valid HTML

Comment: Thank you, I would like to build a program that accepts an input string then draws it as a formatted string in a view, I have no idea how to partition the long given string int smaller parts correctly. Would you mind offering a method or an example I can follow ?

Answer (score 1):

All new browser releases should converge on the [HTML5 parsing algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/parsing.html).

Answer (score -1):

The easiest option is to use an MFC HTML View. This embeds an Internet Explorer control in your view window and supports all HTML formatting, styes, stylesheets, javascript - everything. If you want to restrict the types of HTML tags that can be used you have the option of parsing the text and removing or replacing the disallowed tag before inserting it into the control.

In your input validation you simply search the input string for an opening angle bracket (`<`) and check to see if the tag at that location is allowed. You could say limit this to `<b>` and `<i>` as in your example. If the tag isn't allowed just change the open angle bracket to `&lt;`. This will cause it to be displayed as `<` and not be interpreted as an HTML tag by the browser control